# monitoring estimator progress and sklearn wrappers

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am implementing my own sklearn estimator class which fits a model by minimising a custom loss function iteratively using SGD. I have written it in such a way that I can supply a validation data set via `set_params` and it will regularly measure performance on the training and validation sets during the SGD iteration and store the results in a `progress_` attribute.

This works fine if I instantiate the class myself, but what happens if I want to use it via one of the sklearn wrappers like `GridSearchCV`? When doing cross-validation the validation set is
different for each fold but I can't see a way to tell `GridSearchCV` to update the parameters of my estimator accordingly.